# Is there any Biblical basis for hating homosexuals?

Tags: biblical-basis, hate, homosexuality, violence

As I was raised: God is **all-loving**, and He wants us to be all-loving too.

But, as you may know, homosexuals—particularly in America—have been shown hatred, and even violence [(1)](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110830023018AAfSQUr)[(2)](http://www.jesusneedsnewpr.net/wtf-christian-talk-show-host-praises-countries-who-executepunish-gays-lesbians-unreal/)[(3)](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110830023018AAfSQUr)[(4)](http://www.flynews.com/2011/01/24/ga-man-attacked-for-being-gay.html) from some members of the Christian community. The Wikipedia article on [Christianity and homosexuality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christianity_and_homosexuality) suggests some of the views from various denominations, but it's largest claim remains unsupported (i.e. that "most Christian denominations welcome people attracted to the same sex, but teach that homosexual relationships and sexual acts are sinful." Check the references, they are broken links or only refer to the Methodist Church, so they don't speak for "most Christian denominations").

As I dug deeper into [the Hebrew Bible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_in_the_Hebrew_Bible) and [the New Testament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homosexuality_in_the_New_Testament), I saw some passages which indicated that homosexuality might be a sin, but the articles are poorly written and lack verifiable citations. Either way, I wasn't able to find any indication that God condones violence by mankind towards homosexuals. You would think that those who so vehemently hate homosexuals would also think that homosexuals are going to Hell when they die; that their fate will be gruesome enough such that anything a human does to add to it prematurely would be like kicking someone who's already dead. Maybe they really haven't thought that one through?

So I'm curious **if there is any Biblical support for the idea that God wants us to be cruel to homosexuals** (or anyone for that matter). Please carefully note that I'm not merely asking if the Bible is against homosexuality; I'm asking if there is a basis for **showing hatred towards others**, particularly gays.

Comment: We should love those that hate us, Jesus hung out with those outcast, he hung out with those despised, and loved all.  If we follow his example, we won't hate anyone, but, unfortunately, Jesus as a role-model seems to be outdated.

Comment: I'm not at all sure I'd agree with *particularly in America*. The worst Christian persecution of gay people is probably in Africa, particularly [Uganda](http://www.boxturtlebulletin.com/tag/uganda). That is, admittedly, partly incited by American preachers, but we can't lay all the blame in the USA.

Comment: This question should be completely rewritten to admit that there are a very few people who claim to be Christians who show this kind of hatred.  Christians themselves are quite hated as well, oftentimes much worse, not for hating homosexuals, which they do not, but for merely believing that homosexuality is one of many things which the Bible classifies as immoral.

Comment: @TRiG There is also much Islamic influence in Africa, which has led to much persecution of many people groups, including homosexuals.

Comment: To close voters, I'm not sure this is off-topic or primarily opinion based. It is very clearly asking for Biblical Basis, which is a format that his been traditionally accepted on this site. When self-identified Christians hold signs that say "God hates Gays" I think is is perfectly fair to ask for a Biblical basis for that.

Comment: I don't think you should hate homosexuals any more than you should hate people who work on the Sabbath, whenever that may technically be these days. They're both outlined in Leviticus. Should we respect one law and not the other? Or just learn by the words and actions of Jesus and love one another? Many people don't realize how many Levitical laws basically say to kill people for a great deal of things. Almost all of them are conveniently forgotten when it comes down to picking on someone for their sexual preferences.

Comment: This is definitely a Truth question, and I'm not sure if it's possible to edit it to be otherwise without invalidating all the answers.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @fredsbend in that the question is in scope as long as it is only seeking a biblical basis (if any) for negative attitudes towards homosexuals.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I think a lot of the fat could be trimmed, but the last paragraph, the essence of this question, is not really a Truth question. I think if the junk was removed then it would probably be fine. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @fredsbend A Biblical basis question should ask "what is the Biblical basis for" or "Biblical basis against" something. Not "is there any Biblical basis?"; that's a Truth question. _Every_ answer basically says, "No Biblical basis for hating gays, but it _does_ condemn homosexual _behavior_." Each answer would have odd emphases if the question asked for "Biblical basis against" and would simply be invalid if the question asked for "Biblical basis for." Standards were simply different when this question was asked.

Comment: @DickHarfield See my comment above to fredsbend.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude I take your point, and a nuance fredsbend and I probably both overlooked. Presumably the issue could be resolved simply by changing the question to "What is the Biblical basis for hating homosexuals?"

Comment: @DickHarfield That would invalidate every single answer though.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude "God hates old answers to old off-topic questions". I've updated it, without regard to the answers.

Comment: @fredsbend I just don't see why we should change a 4-year-old question with seven answers, into a _different_ question with 0 answers. If someone wants to ask this question, they can. Why not close this one and let someone else ask if they want to?

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude IMHO the 2nd, the last and the 2nd last answers do not address the question no matter how asked (regardlessof any upvotes). As to the rest, I would be happy with answers to a question that asked "What is the ..." if they said, "There is no biblical basis," as long as they went on to show (or seek to show) that there could be no such basis.

Comment: @DickHarfield If a Christian group believes there is a Biblical basis, then it is not appropriate to answer "there is no Biblical basis" on this site. I believe that firmly. I may _strongly_ disagree with a group's exegesis, but if we're reporting "just the facts," then the Westboro Baptist Church's Biblical basis for hatred is a valid answer and all other churches' Biblical basis for non-hatred is not (though it could be an excellent answer to a _different_ question). But you're right that a couple answers here don't attempt to show any Biblical basis for anything.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude Well, close voters can see our comments. If it does get closed, I'll ask the question, but not before it's closed.

Comment: I've rolled back the edits and voted to close based on what seems to be a meta [consensus about old questions that are now off-topic](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3916/9289).

Comment: The "particularly in America" remaining included is hardly necessary, and was worth a down vote due to the deliberate bias it expresses.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### In general

> [**Romans 12:16-21 (ESV)**](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans%2012:16-21&version=ESV)
>    <sup>16</sup>  Live in harmony with one another. Do not be haughty, but associate with the lowly. Never be wise in your own sight. <sup>17</sup>  Repay no one evil for evil, but give thought to do what is honorable in the sight of all. <sup>18</sup> **If possible, so far as it depends on you, live peaceably with all.** <sup>19</sup> Beloved, never avenge yourselves, but leave it to the wrath of God, for it is written, "Vengeance is mine, I will repay, says the Lord." <sup>20</sup> To the contrary, "if your enemy is hungry, feed him; if he is thirsty, give him something to drink; for by so doing you will heap burning coals on his head." <sup>21</sup> Do not be overcome by evil, but **overcome evil with good**.

If we have the choice, we should live in peace with all and be good to everyone. Even if they're evil. Even if they're our enemy.

#### Specifically regarding homosexuals

The Bible condemns homosexual **acts**, not having homosexual temptations. We can't judge anyone for what they didn't choose -- even Jesus was tempted, so temptations are not sin.

We don't know for sure if [you can be born a homosexual](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/does-god-create-some-people-heterosexual-and-others-homosexual/1603#1603), but it's certainly possible (even probable, science seems to tell us). That's all the more reason to try and be understanding with homosexual people. Do note that being born one way or another is no excuse for sinning, and we shouldn't act like the Bible approves of homosexual relationships and activities.

Comment: See also: [Should biblical laws apply to non-Christians?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1148)

Comment: Good answer.  I would like to add that all sin is equal before God.  That means anger, gluttony, getting drunk are all equally abhorrent to God.  See James 2:10.  Sin is sin, and we all have a tendency to compare our sin to others in an attempt to justify our own short comings.  When we do that it is not biblical and there is no biblical support for judging the sins of others (See Matthew 7: 1-5 and Matthew 12:31).  Finally, confronting sin is called for between brothers in Christ (see 1 John 5:16-17), but in a loving way.  We are not called to confront immorality of those not born again.

Comment: @AdamHeeg In that same passage in 1John, you see that there is sin that is not mortal (sin not leading unto death) which is a point against "all sin being equal before God."  On the other hand, your point is clear that God would not be pleased with sin in general, be it a greater or less sin as alluded to in 1 John.

Answer (score 9):

Hatred should not be shown towards anyone.

> For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God (Romans 3:23)

The punishment of homosexuality

> Likewise also the men, leaving the natural use of the woman, burned in their lust for one another, men with men committing what is shameful, and **receiving in themselves the penalty of their error which was due**. (Romans 1:27 NKJV)

Some of the Early Church was Homosexual

> Do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived. Neither fornicators, nor idolaters, nor adulterers, nor **homosexuals**, nor sodomites, nor thieves, nor covetous, nor drunkards, nor revilers, nor extortioners will inherit the kingdom of God. **And such were some of you**. But you were washed, but you were sanctified, but you were justified in the name of the Lord Jesus and by the Spirit of our God. (1 Corinthians 6:9-11 NKJV)

We have been given specific instruction on how to deal with Homosexuals **OUTSIDE THE BODY** who are sexually immoral.

> I wrote to you in my epistle not to keep company with sexually immoral people. Yet I certainly did not mean with the sexually immoral people of this world, or with the covetous, or extortioners, or idolaters, since then you would need to go out of the world. (1 Corinthians 5:9-10 NKJV)
>
> **But those who are outside God judges.** Therefore “put away from yourselves the evil person.” (1 Corinthians 5:13 NKJV)

We have been given specific instruction on how to deal with Homosexuals **IN THE BODY** who **CONTINUE IN SEXUAL IMMORALITY**

> Moreover if your brother sins against you, go and tell him his fault between you and him alone. If he hears you, you have gained your brother. But if he will not hear, take with you one or two more, that ‘by the mouth of two or three witnesses every word may be established.’ And if he refuses to hear them, tell it to the church. But if he refuses even to hear the church, let him be to you like a heathen and a tax collector. (Matthew 18:15-17 NKJV)

So instruction was also given to the church.

> But now I have written to you not to keep company with anyone named a brother, who is sexually immoral, or covetous, or an idolater, or a reviler, or a drunkard, or an extortioner—not even to eat with such a person. (1 Corinthians 5:11 NKJV)

And also an example of sexual immorality was given to show exactly how to handle it

> It is actually reported that there is sexual immorality among you, and such sexual immorality as is not even named among the Gentiles—that a man has his father’s wife! And you are puffed up, and have not rather mourned, **that he who has done this deed might be taken away from among you**. (1 Corinthians 5:1-2 NKJV)

Delivery of the Punishment

> In the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, when you are gathered together, along with my spirit, with the power of our Lord Jesus Christ, deliver such a one to Satan for the destruction of the flesh, that his spirit may be saved in the day of the Lord Jesus. (1 Corinthians 5:4-5 NKJV)
>
> But those who are outside God judges. **Therefore “put away from yourselves the evil person.”** (1 Corinthians 5:13 NKJV)

**There should be no hate for homosexuals. For God fulfills the law.**

> “Do not think that I came to destroy the Law or the Prophets. I did not come to destroy **but to fulfill**. (Matthew 5:17 NKJV)

Therefore since in God's opinion it's a detestable act.

> If a man lies with a male as he lies with a woman, both of them have committed an abomination. They shall surely be put to death. Their blood shall be upon them. (Leviticus 20:13 NKJV)

God will deliver the punishment

> **But those who are outside God judges.** Therefore “put away from yourselves the evil person.” (1 Corinthians 5:13 NKJV)

For He delivers the death penalty

> So when they continued asking Him, He raised Himself up and said to them, “He who is without sin among you, **let him throw a stone at her first**.” (John 8:7 NKJV)

Comment: In your very last sentence, you write "For he is the one to deliver the death penalty". I'm presuming you mean to capitalizing the "he" to "He", implying God is the one to deliver the punishment. What you quote (both as you wrote it and in the Bible itself, "let HIM throw a stone..." is **uncapitalized**, implying not God doing the throwing but a human being. So that quote would suggest that — in whatever example of punishment that is referring to — humankind should deliver the punishment...

Comment: A larger problem I have with your answer is that you quote a wide range of Biblical passages out of context to support your claims, many of which do not directly support what you are saying. Take the first sentence, for example: "Hatred should not be shown towards anyone." A quote from the Bible saying "For all have sinned and fall short of the Glory of God" does not mean that no one should show hatred to anyone. It means that all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God... The context of that passage talks about Israelites and non-Israelites being equal...

Comment: @stoicfury At the time for the stoning, Jesus prays “He who is without sin among you, let him throw a stone at her first.” implying for God do the throwing. For the Father has decided to complete the law. "He who leads into captivity shall go into captivity; he who kills with the sword must be killed with the sword. Here is the patience and the faith of the saints." (Revelation 13:10 NKJV) and no long us "To him who strikes you on the one cheek, offer the other also. And from him who takes away your cloak, do not withhold your tunic either." (Luke 6:29) So no only God is to deliver now.

Comment: Who will render to every man according to his deeds (Romans 2:6 NKJV)

Comment: @stoicfury perhaps I should have included "Let all bitterness, wrath, anger, clamor, and evil speaking be put away from you, with all malice." (Ephesians 4:31 NKJV) and the reason why is because "For all have sinned and fall short of the glory of God" (Romans 3:23 NKJV)

Comment: @stoicfury for no longer are we to fear man because God will inflict the wrath. "But if our unrighteousness demonstrates the righteousness of God, what shall we say? Is God unjust who inflicts wrath? (I speak as a man.)" (Romans 3:5) and also here "Beloved, do not avenge yourselves, but rather give place to wrath; for it is written, “Vengeance is Mine, I will repay,” says the Lord. " (Romans 12:19 NKJV)

Comment: @stoicfury Now the Laws of Existence is so this, that every action has an opposite and equal reaction. So specifically in response to "So that quote would suggest that — in whatever example of punishment that is referring to — humankind should deliver the punishment... " When humankind delivers the punishment, that's the expression of the law through the flesh. And all expression of the flesh is so under the law. So for he who picks up a stone to throw, the laws of motion will attack the "one throwing the stone". "..touch·in his·hand·for·stone·he will stone·or·arrow·he will arrow"-Exodus 19:30

Answer (score 5):

First off, a point of terminology.  There is no Biblical (or historical, for that matter) basis for the *existence* of "homosexual people" in the first place.  The concept of "sexual orientation" as an inherent trait seems to be a modern concept, invented for political purposes and unsupported by objective facts.

The Bible condemns *homosexual acts* in very strong terms.  However, it does not condone taking the punishment for even the most sinful of acts into one's own hands, nor is violence or hatred against others permitted.  The Sermon on the Mount makes it quite clear that, as even such small bits of hate as angry words can lead to sins as great as murder, that they should be avoided entirely in order to follow the principles of the Gospel.  In fact, Jesus places such strong importance on this principle that he places reconciliation and the avoidance of anger and conflict even above such weighty matters as bringing an offering/donation to the house of the Lord:

> **[Matthew 5:21-24](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%205:21-24)**
>
> 21 Ye have heard that it was said of them of old time, Thou shalt not kill; and whosoever shall kill shall be in danger of the judgment:
>
> 22 But I say unto you, That whosoever is angry with his brother without a cause shall be in danger of the judgment: and whosoever shall say to his brother, Raca, shall be in danger of the council: but whosoever shall say, Thou fool, shall be in danger of hell fire.
>
> 23 Therefore if thou bring thy gift to the altar, and there rememberest that thy brother hath ought against thee;
>
> 24 Leave there thy gift before the altar, and go thy way; first be reconciled to thy brother, and then come and offer thy gift.

It's also worth noting that, while violence against "homosexual people" by religious people tends to get a lot of coverage in the media, government statistics show that the greatest source of violence against homosexuals by far is *domestic* violence, perpetrated by their own partners.  Why this is, and why it is not covered more widely by the media, is the subject of a different question, most likely for a different site.

Comment: Re: Your last paragraph on domestic violence. My understanding is that [most domestic violence against lesbians is at the hands of former, male partners](http://www.boxturtlebulletin.com/2008/07/21/2386). This does count as "domestic violence", but it also contradicts the point you're making. Do you have any studies to back up your claim?

Comment: Sexual orientation is *not* a "modern concept". Hindu scriptures have talked about homosexuality and gender variance, calling temptation a "spiritual goal of life".

Answer (score 1):

**Mark 12:31 NIV**

> The second is this: 'Love your neighbor as yourself.' There is no
>   commandment greater than these.

What is important is that it does NOT say, "love your neighbor as yourself, if he believes like you do".  Also, I would suggest that it would be against Jesus' teachings to even consider to hate someone because they do not have the same life rules as you.

While I believe that homosexual sexual activities are unnatural, it is not my job to judge the people who commit these acts.  I have better things to occupy my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Read Romans 1-2 (that's chapters one and two), which contain verses quoted to condemn homosexuality. You will see that Paul is making a point that in condemning we are judging and are guilty of plenty of our own sins.

> Therefore thou art inexcusable, O man, whosoever thou art that judgest: for wherein thou judgest another, thou condemnest thyself; for thou that judgest doest the same things.
>   **Romans 2:1**

Consider also:

> If a man say, I love God, and hateth his brother, he is a liar: for he that loveth not his brother whom he hath seen, how can he love God whom he hath not seen?
>   **1 John 4:20**

We are explicitly taught to love everyone:

> 11 Now God himself and our Father, and our Lord Jesus Christ, direct our way unto you.
>   12 And the Lord make you to increase and abound in love one toward another, and toward all men, even as we do toward you:
>   13 To the end he may stablish your hearts unblameable in holiness before God, even our Father, at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ with all his saints.
>   **1 Thessalonians 3:11-13**

Comment: If we are taught to love everyone, why does God kill lots of people? Also, if God made everyone, he must have made the people he kills as well, which seems silly because he obviously knew how they would behave when he made them in the first place. How does one reconcile God's clearly irrational and violent behavior in the Old Testament with his noticeably softer approach in the New Testament? You say God wants us to love everyone, but sometimes it sure doesn't seem like it in the Bible...

Comment: Try to remember, God is God, you and I are not.  No person will every understand God's ways on earth.  There are different viewpoints on how to answer your multiple questions.  I try very hard to accept the things I cannot understand and will never know in this life.  However, you could start a new question and ask what are the different theological responses to {insert a question here}.  Remember, no on can prove God exists to you, nor can anyone prove he doesn't exist.  Faith is all we have no matter what you end up believing and trusting in.